# Counting null and non-null values in a single query

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
create table us
(
 a number
);
```

Now I have data like:

```
a
1
2
3
4
null
null
null
8
9
```

Now I need a single query to count null **and** not null values in column a

Comment: Hi,
where do you need to this kind of counting database code in what language database are we talking
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: ??? Isn't it just this ???

`SELECT count(*) FROM us WHERE a IS NULL or a IS NOT NULL`

works in Postgres

Comment: simply do `select count(*) - count(a) as num_null, count(a) as num_not_null from us;` counting a column returns the number of non null values, substract it from count(*) and you're gold.

Answer (score 330):

This works for Oracle and SQL Server (you might be able to get it to work on another RDBMS):

```
select sum(case when a is null then 1 else 0 end) count_nulls
     , count(a) count_not_nulls 
  from us;
```

Or:

```
select count(*) - count(a), count(a) from us;
```

Comment: Using the distinction between `count(*)` and `count(a)` also works well with `group by`

Comment: @shannon I agree, `COUNT(a)` is a useful comment to add, but this does throw a warning/error depending on your stack and might warrant a comment in code. I would prefer the `SUM` method.

Comment: Prefer `count(*)` to `count(1)`

Comment: @LeiZhao - Does it make any difference in speed?

Comment: @Ωmega No difference in speed, I believe, at least for any recent version of RDBMS (within one or two decades).  I preferred `count(*)` not for performance, but for clarity of meaning.

Comment: both count(*) and count(1) will yield same performance as '*' denotes "anything that feasible", so with *, you leave things on mysql engine to determine the best performance method.  count(1), however increases the readability.

Answer (score 86):

If I understood correctly you want to count all NULL and all NOT NULL in a column...

If that is correct:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM us WHERE a IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) FROM us WHERE a IS NOT NULL
```

Edited to have the full query, after reading the comments :]

---

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 'null_tally' AS narrative 
  FROM us 
 WHERE a IS NULL 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 'not_null_tally' AS narrative 
  FROM us 
 WHERE a IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 56):

Here is a quick and dirty version that works on Oracle :

```
select sum(case a when null then 1 else 0) "Null values",
       sum(case a when null then 0 else 1) "Non-null values"
from us
```

Comment: Similar syntax would work in SQL Server as well. Also, doing it this way will only scan the table once; the UNION solutions will do two table scans. Irrelevant for small tables, very important for huge ones.

Comment: Only change for SQL Server is `"Null values"` would have to become `'Null values'`. Single quotes, not doubles.

Comment: SQLServer uses an *index scan* for this query vs two *index seeks* using a union. On a table with 40.000 rows, there is no speed difference.

Comment: On a table with 11.332.581 rows, there are two *table scans*, no noticable speed difference (actualy, the union is *slightly* faster).

Comment: This did not work for me in Oracle 11g. The version @user155789 posted with "case when a is null then 1 else 0 end" was the syntax that worked.

Comment: Following up on Lieven's comment, SQL Server also requires "end" for the case statement (prior to closing the parens).

Comment: I have tried to use about every version I could think off in SQL developer and nothing seems to work (with/without end, single/double brackets, case when a / case a is null), any tips for me ?

Comment: Even simpler:
count(case when a is null then 1 else 1 end) AS Count_A

Comment: Warning - syntax of the CASE... is wrong here!

Comment: PostgreSQL syntax:
select 
sum(CASE WHEN a is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  )  "Non-null values" ,
(CASE WHEN a is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  )  "Null values"  
from A

Answer (score 35):

for non nulls

```
select count(a)
from us
```

for nulls

```
select count(*)
from us

minus 

select count(a)
from us
```

Hence

```
SELECT COUNT(A) NOT_NULLS
FROM US

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(A) NULLS
FROM US
```

ought to do the job

Better in that the column titles come out correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(A) NOT_NULL, COUNT(*) - COUNT(A) NULLS
FROM US
```

In some testing on my system, it costs a full table scan.

Comment: Good gravy, man, look at the execution plans for these queries. You're kicking off table scans left and right, especially where there's such a bloody simple statement (`select count(*) from t where a is null`) that does this.

Comment: I don't have a database handy to look, but either the column is indexed or not.   If it is, it happens via a range scan, otherwise, you are pretty much left with a full table scan.  In oracle, NULLs are not stored in the index, so I suspect you example isn't much better. Your milage may very.

Comment: @EvilTeach: Indexes are only helpful when you're not pulling back > ~10% of the rows. After that, full scans are initiated. In this case, you'll get the scan at least once, if not twice.

Answer (score 28):

As i understood your query, You just run this script and get Total Null,Total NotNull rows,

```
select count(*) - count(a) as 'Null', count(a) as 'Not Null' from us;
```

Answer (score 27):

usually i use this trick

```
select sum(case when a is null then 0 else 1 end) as count_notnull,
       sum(case when a is null then 1 else 0 end) as count_null
from tab
group by a
```

Comment: You need to swap `count_notnull` and `count_null`, now it gives opposite results :)

Answer (score 26):

Just to provide yet another alternative, Postgres 9.4+ [allows applying a `FILTER` to aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE a IS NULL) count_nulls,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE a IS NOT NULL) count_not_nulls
FROM us;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/80a24/5

Answer (score 6):

This is little tricky. Assume the table has just one column, then the Count(1) and Count(*) will give different values.

```
set nocount on
    declare @table1 table (empid int)
    insert @table1 values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(NULL),(11),(12),(NULL),(13),(14);

    select * from @table1
    select COUNT(1) as "COUNT(1)" from @table1
    select COUNT(empid) "Count(empid)" from @table1
```

[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLH2y.png)

As you can see in the image, The first result shows the table has 16 rows. out of which two rows are NULL. So when we use **Count(*)** the query engine counts the number of rows, So we got count result as 16. But in case of **Count(empid)** it counted the non-NULL-values in the column *empid*. So we got the result as 14.

so whenever we are using COUNT(Column) make sure we take care of NULL values as shown below.

```
select COUNT(isnull(empid,1)) from @table1
```

will count both NULL and Non-NULL values.

**Note**: Same thing applies even when the table is made up of more than one column. Count(1) will give total number of rows irrespective of NULL/Non-NULL values. Only when the column values are counted using Count(Column) we need to take care of NULL values.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue: to count all distinct values, counting null values as 1, too. A simple count doesn't work in this case, as it does not take null values into account.

Here's a snippet that works on SQL and does not involve selection of new values.
Basically, once performed the distinct, also return the row number in a new column (n) using the row_number() function, then perform a count on that column:

```
SELECT COUNT(n)
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [MyColumn] ASC) n
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [MyColumn]
                    FROM [MyTable]
        ) items  
) distinctItems
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'Null' 
         ELSE 'Not Null' 
       END a, 
       Count(1) 
FROM   us 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'Null' 
            ELSE 'Not Null' 
          END
```

Answer (score 3):

use ISNULL embedded function.

---

Comment: This is also a worthy answer. I personally found that COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(A,'')) works even better then COUNT(DISTINCT A) + SUM (CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two solutions:

```
Select count(columnname) as countofNotNulls, count(isnull(columnname,1))-count(columnname) AS Countofnulls from table name
```

OR

```
Select count(columnname) as countofNotNulls, count(*)-count(columnname) AS Countofnulls from table name
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT 
   SUM(ISNULL(a)) AS all_null,
   SUM(!ISNULL(a)) AS all_not_null
FROM us;
```

Simple!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MS Sql Server...

```
SELECT COUNT(0) AS 'Null_ColumnA_Records',
(
    SELECT COUNT(0)
    FROM your_table
    WHERE ColumnA IS NOT NULL
) AS 'NOT_Null_ColumnA_Records'
FROM your_table
WHERE ColumnA IS NULL;
```

I don't recomend you doing this... but here you have it (in the same table as result)

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(isnull(NullableColumn,-1))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are either wrong or extremely out of date.

The simple and correct way of doing this query is using `COUNT_IF` function.

```
SELECT
  COUNT_IF(a IS NULL) AS nulls,
  COUNT_IF(a IS NOT NULL) AS not_nulls
FROM
  us
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(NULLs) AS 'NULLS', SUM(NOTNULLs) AS 'NOTNULLs' FROM 
    (select count(*) AS 'NULLs', 0 as 'NOTNULLs' FROM us WHERE a is null
    UNION select 0 as 'NULLs', count(*) AS 'NOTNULLs' FROM us WHERE a is not null) AS x
```

It's fugly, but it will return a single record with 2 cols indicating the count of nulls vs non nulls.

Answer (score 1):

This works in T-SQL. If you're just counting the number of something and you want to include the nulls, use COALESCE instead of case.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#us') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #us

CREATE TABLE #us
    (
    a INT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO #us VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(8),(9)

SELECT * FROM #us

SELECT CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NON-NULL' END AS 'NULL?',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NON-NULL' END) AS 'Count'
    FROM #us
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NON-NULL' END

SELECT COALESCE(CAST(a AS NVARCHAR),'NULL') AS a,
        COUNT(COALESCE(CAST(a AS NVARCHAR),'NULL')) AS 'Count'
    FROM #us
    GROUP BY COALESCE(CAST(a AS NVARCHAR),'NULL')
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Alberto, I added the rollup.

```
 SELECT [Narrative] = CASE 
 WHEN [Narrative] IS NULL THEN 'count_total' ELSE    [Narrative] END
,[Count]=SUM([Count]) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) [Count], 'count_nulls' AS [Narrative]  
FROM [CrmDW].[CRM].[User]  
WHERE [EmployeeID] IS NULL 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 'count_not_nulls ' AS narrative 
FROM [CrmDW].[CRM].[User] 
WHERE [EmployeeID] IS NOT NULL) S 
GROUP BY [Narrative] WITH CUBE;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ALL_VALUES
    ,COUNT(ALL_VALUES)
FROM(
        SELECT 
        NVL2(A,'NOT NULL','NULL') AS ALL_VALUES 
        ,NVL(A,0)
        FROM US
)
GROUP BY ALL_VALUES
```

Answer (score 0):

if its mysql, you can try something like this.

```
select 
   (select count(*) from TABLENAME WHERE a = 'null') as total_null, 
   (select count(*) from TABLENAME WHERE a != 'null') as total_not_null
FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wanted it in a single record:

```
select 
  (select count(*) from tbl where colName is null) Nulls,
  (select count(*) from tbl where colName is not null) NonNulls
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

for counting not null values

```
select count(*) from us where a is not null;
```

for counting null values

```
 select count(*) from us where a is null;
```

Comment: The op asked for single query :)

Answer (score 0):

I created the table in postgres 10 and both of the following worked:

`select count(*) from us`

and

`select count(a is null) from us`

Comment: `a IS NULL` produces `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and COUNT() will count all NOT NULL values. So `count(a is null)` will return the count of all rows.

Comment: @ypresto I agree with you, the answer is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted the "**null distribution**" amongst multiple columns:

```
SELECT
       (CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT-NULL' END) AS a_null,
       (CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT-NULL' END) AS b_null,
       (CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT-NULL' END) AS c_null,
       ...
       count(*)
FROM us
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3,...
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3,...
```

As per the '...' it is easily extendable to more columns, as many as needed

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the count of all values (including `NULL`) in MySQL and this worked:

```sql
SELECT
  _a,
  COUNT(_a)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(a, 'NULL') as _a
    FROM
      us
  ) AS T
GROUP BY
  _a;
```

Answer (score -4):

Number of elements where a is null:

```
select count(a) from us where a is null;
```

Number of elements where a is not null:

```
select count(a) from us where a is not null;
```

Comment: The question is for a single query.