# "INSERT INTO" an output table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select hour, count(*)
from table
group by hour
```

I want the return to look like:

```
hour  count
8     1
9     0
10    3
```

But instead it looks like:

```
hour  count
8     1
10    3
```

This is because there were no entries in `table` for 9. The only solution I can think of is using an `insert into` statement wrapped around the query. So, something like:

```
insert into (
select hour, count(*)
from table
group by hour)
values (9, 0)
```

However this isn't proper syntax in Spark SQL.

Is it possible to insert into a table that's being generated as a result of a query without saving that table to a database? Is there an alternative way to accomplish what I want to accomplish?

Comment: how about union. select hour, count(*) from table group by hour union select 9 ,0

Comment: Returns `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: missing EOF at 'select' near 'union'; line 28 pos 0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1271845/5308100 See this answer. Should do the trick I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work with any database engine:

```
select hour, sum(records) totalRecords
from (
select 0 hour, 0 records
from table
union
select 1 hour, 0 records
from table
...
union 
select 23 hour, 0 records
from table
union
select hour, count(*) records
from table
group by hour
) derivedTable
```

This assumes of course, that hour represents the hour of the day.