# SQL query - Cannot COUNT right for 2 out of 3 columns

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to make a less bulky version from the original data file and add 3 COUNT columns in the far right. I have found success to add COUNT column for COMPANY WEBSITE, but I am having trouble with the rest of two. I believe my problem is about not knowing how to use the `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` when I want multiple column outputs.

Original Data

| STATE | COMPANY WEBSITE | IMAGE 1 | IMAGE 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | xxx.com | aaa | zzz |
| NY | xxx.com | NULL | yyy |
| NY | xxx.com | bbb | NULL |
| NY | xxx.com | ccc | NULL |
| NY | yyy.com | ddd | xxx |
| NY | yyy.com | NULL | NULL |
| NY | yyy.com | eee | NULL |
| NY | yyy.com | NULL | NULL |

This is what I've tried:

```sql
SELECT [STATE], 
       [COMPANY WEBSITE], 
       COUNT([COMPANY WEBSITE]) AS [COMPANY COUNT], 
       COUNT([IMAGE 1]) AS [IMAGE 1 COUNT], 
       COUNT([IMAGE 2]) as [IMAGE 2 COUNT] 
FROM [DATA FILE NAME]
GROUP BY [COMPANY WEBSITE]
```

I was expecting the the following result:

| STATE | COMPANY WEBSITE | COMPANY COUNT | IMAGE 1 COUNT | IMAGE 2 COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | xxx.com | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| NY | yyy.com | 4 | 2 | 1 |

But the result I get is this:

| STATE | COMPANY WEBSITE | COMPANY COUNT | IMAGE 1 COUNT | IMAGE 2 COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | xxx.com | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| NY | yyy.com | 4 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: denormalising like this will come back to haunt you. I'd suggest creating a view with supporting indexes to make querying efficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271810/counting-null-and-non-null-values-in-a-single-query

Comment: Are you just wanting to count non-NULL fields, which is a simple `COUNT_IF(IMAGE_1 is not NULL)` or do you want to count unique non-NULLs, which is considerably more complicated.

Comment: @KenY-N, `count(IMAGE_1)` counts non-null values only.

Comment: Maybe it's the string `'NULL'` rather than an actual `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

I am using you test data and this returned correct result..

```
 SELECT State, 
       company_website, 
       COUNT(company_website) AS [COMPANY COUNT], 
       COUNT(Image1) AS [IMAGE 1 COUNT], 
       COUNT(Image2) as [IMAGE 2 COUNT] 
FROM BikeStores_starschema.dbo.test 
GROUP BY company_website,State

    State   company_website COMPANY COUNT   IMAGE 1 COUNT   IMAGE 2 COUNT
     NY      xxx.com            4             3                 2
     NY      yyy.com              4          2                  1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it just refuse to work for me. I guess it's because I am using Windows Powershell for the SQL? Sorry I am totally new and I don't know if there's a difference between them